# iOS - fastlane deliver, localized App Store description from strings file?

Tags: ios, app-store, fastlane, fastlane-deliver

I'm getting ready to have my app localized into other languages.

I'm using `NSLocalizedStringWithDefaultValue` to provide default English text within code, although I guess none of that maybe relevant.

I'm not adding localized text directly to nib or storyboards, everything is in my strings file.

I'll probably end up uploading those to a localization site.

So I'd like to use fastlane deliver to upload screenshots and meta data.

However I'd like to find a method where I can pickup values from my strings files.

So I guess my question is, how can I get my strings value into my deliver text file?

Or is there a better / quicker approach I should use?

Comment: I guess I'm trying to figure out the least effort approach for localized descriptions.

Comment: So you want a Ruby way, so it integrates with `fastlane`, of reading a specific key=value in your localized strings file to the deliver text file?

Comment: Yes that’s correct